# update field by extending original value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I update a field in SQL in a way that I keep the original value and just add a prefix or suffix to it?

```
update mytable set myfield = 'ABC'+myfield where id = 123
```

does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Just use MySQL syntax:

```
update mytable
    set myfield = concat('ABC', myfield)
    where id = 123 ;
```

Note:  If `myfield` could be `NULL`, then you might want:

```
update mytable
    set myfield = concat('ABC', coalesce(myfield, ''))
    where id = 123 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, using `concat` function:

```
update mytable set myfield = concat('ABC',myfield) where id = 123
```